# Print AngularJS function as attributes in an HTML element

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to add certain attributes to multiple different elements in an existing DOM, but I am concerned that I may need to add or remove certain attributes in the future, so I thought I can write an angular function that returns these attributes and call that function from any location in my HTML.

The function is pretty straight forward, it just returns some attributes:

```
$scope.getHelpTextAttributes = function(helptext,placement){
            return 'uib-tooltip="{{helptext.'+helptext+'}}" \
            tooltip-placement="'+placement+'" \
            tooltip-popup-close-delay="1000" \
            tooltip-append-to-body="true" \
            tooltip-class="explainer-tooltip"'
        }
    )
```

And I can call it when putting it between `<pre>` tags like so:

```
<pre>
{{getHelpTextAttributes('test','left')}}
</pre>
```

This returns:

```
<pre class="ng-binding">                
    uib-tooltip="{{helptext.test}}"             
    tooltip-placement="left"            
    tooltip-popup-close-delay="1000"            
    tooltip-append-to-body="true"           
    tooltip-class="explainer-tooltip"
</pre>
```

However when I call that function from inside an html element like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star principal-menu-btn" {{getHelpTextAttributes('test','left')}}></span> Set Default
```

I get that following html:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star principal-menu-btn" "{{gethelptextattributes('test','left')}}"=""></span>
```

How do I (or can I even can) call an angular function without putting it between tags or putting it as a value to a certain attribute and can I achieve the above using a different method?

Comment: Do you have `getHelpTextAttributes` function in a directive?

Comment: So, you just want to have a reusable function which adds attributes to a given html tag right?

Comment: @RaviTeja I can add it in, will google it and see what it does.
And yes you're correct I want to have a reusable function that can be easily modified that adds html attributes to the element that calls it.